# Pre declaration and the inclusion of header files/bese on Qt

Tags: c++, qt

New to Qt.
For "C++ GUI Qt 4" in a book to see, in the second chapter, a section of code, the book is written not included with this several related header files (such as ), but the use of some pre declaration, this is a compilation of some faster. But I was wrong to compile:" invalid use of incomplete type:"

finddialog.h

```
#ifndef FINDDIALOG_H
#define FINDDIALOG_H
#include <QDialog>
#include <QHBoxLayout>

//#include <QLabel>
//#include <QCheckBox>
//#include <QLineEdit>
//#include <QPushButton>

class QLabel;
class QCheckBox;
class QLineEdit;
class QPushButton;

class finddialog:public QDialog
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    finddialog(QWidget *parent = 0);
signals:
    void findNext(const QString &str,Qt::CaseSensitivity cs);
    void findPrevious(const QString &str,Qt::CaseSensitivity cs);
private slots:
    void findClicked();
    void enableFindButton(const QString &text);
private:
    QLabel *label;
    QLineEdit *lineEdit;
    QCheckBox *caseCheckBox;
    QCheckBox *backwardCheckBox;
    QPushButton *findButton;
    QPushButton *closeButton;
};

#endif // FINDDIALOG_H
```

finddialog.cpp

```
#include <QtGui>
#include "finddialog.h"


finddialog::finddialog(QWidget *parent):QDialog(parent)
{
    label = new QLabel(tr("find &what:"));
    lineEdit = new QLineEdit;
    label->setBuddy(lineEdit);

    caseCheckBox = new QCheckBox(tr("Match &case"));
    backwardCheckBox = new QCheckBox(tr("seach &backward"));

    findButton = new QPushButton(tr("&find"));
    findButton->setDefault(true);
    findButton->setEnabled(false);

    closeButton = new QPushButton(tr("close"));

    connect(lineEdit,SIGNAL(textChanged(const QString &)),this,SLOT(enableFindButton(const QSting &)));
    connect(findButton,SIGNAL(clicked()),this,SLOT(findClicked()));
    connect(closeButton,SIGNAL(clicked()),this,SLOT(close()));
    QHBoxLayout *topLeftLayout = new QHBoxLayout;
    topLeftLayout->addWidget(label);
    topLeftLayout->addWidget(lineEdit);
    QVBoxLayout *leftLayout = new QVBoxLayout;
    leftLayout->addLayout(topLeftLayout);
    leftLayout->addWidget(caseCheckBox);
    leftLayout->addWidget(backwardCheckBox);

    QVBoxLayout *rightLayout = new QVBoxLayout;
    rightLayout->addWidget(findButton);
    rightLayout->addWidget(closeButton);
    rightLayout->addStretch();

    QHBoxLayout *mainLayout = new QHBoxLayout;
    mainLayout->addLayout(leftLayout);
    mainLayout->addLayout(rightLayout);
    setLayout(mainLayout);
    setWindowTitle(tr("Find:"));
    setFixedHeight(sizeHint().height());
}

void finddialog::findClicked()
{
    QString text = lineEdit->text();
    Qt::CaseSensitivity cs = caseCheckBox->isChecked()?Qt::CaseSensitive:Qt::CaseInsensitive;
    if(backwardCheckBox->isChecked())
    {
        emit findPrevious(text,cs);

    }
    else
    {
        emit findNext(text,cs);
    }

}
void finddialog::enableFindButton(const QString &text)
{
    findButton->setEnabled(!text.isEmpty());
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dIr6J.png)

Comment: In your cpp file you need to include <QLabel> , <QLineEdit> ... basically all the `Qt` headers you commented out of your header put those includes in your cpp file.

Comment: 你的意思是添加头文件（#include <QLabel>）还是预声明（QLabel类）？

Comment: I only understand english and perhaps a little spanish. Sorry.

Comment: Sorry.Do you mean adding a header file （#include <QLabel>）or a pre declaration（class QLabel）?

Comment: I mean adding #include <QLabel> to the top of `finddialog.cpp`. Although now when I look at it you have `#include <QtGui>` you may need to move that below `#include "finddialog.h"` I never use `#include <QtGui>`

Comment: But why is the pre declaration wrong?

Comment: That would solve the problem, but I hope you can say more about the pre declaration.Source code:http://www.informit.com/title/0132354160,(Second chapters)

Answer (score 0):

Note that by default the types defined by Qt are placed in a namespace, but a header file does a `using namespace` directive so you mostly don't need to worry about it.  But this means a plain old forward declaration doesn't match the correct name.  The correct way to forward declare classes which belong to the Qt library is:

```
QT_FORWARD_DECLARE_CLASS(QLabel)
QT_FORWARD_DECLARE_CLASS(QCheckBox)
QT_FORWARD_DECLARE_CLASS(QLineEdit)
QT_FORWARD_DECLARE_CLASS(QPushButton)
```

As hinted in the comments, the compiler won't let you do `new Type`, `ptr->member`, or various other things until it has already seen the full definition of the class, not just a forward declaration.  So there's no avoiding needing the includes in your *.cpp file:

```
#include <QLabel>
#include <QCheckBox>
#include <QLineEdit>
#include <QPushButton>
```

Now your one *.cpp file has all the dependencies it needs, plus other *.cpp files that include your *.h file don't necessarily need to spend the extra compile time reading those headers and parsing the contents.

Comment: I changed "class QLabel" to "QT_FORWARD_DECLARE_CLASS(QLabel)", but there was the same mistake.

Comment: Works for me with these changes. What exact error do you get?

Comment: I believe he expected that `QT_FORWARD_DECLARE_CLASS(QLabel)` would remove the need to use `#include <QLabel>` in the cpp file.

Comment: In the "finddialog.cpp",the error is "invalid use of incomplete type".Can you run my code on your computer?

Comment: That's not a complete error message.  I can compile it fine, but can't run it because there's no `main`.

Comment: Source code:informit.com/title/0132354160,(Second chapters).This is the source code, you try to run, I guess my QT version of the problem. Thank you